# Reactjs with firebase data how to dynamically pushing into state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem dynamically pushing my data from firebase to a state array.

base on this(not a dynamic setting since I will also passed different data base on the props of a component that calls this component):

```
memberLists.push({
   fname: freBaseData[frdata].fname,
   mname: freBaseData[frdata].mname,
   lname: freBaseData[frdata].lname
});
```

I want the data i'm pushing be dynamic. I have different components calling this component. And just passing some props, like fname/mname/lname or can be announcements/post/phone numbers.

Right now my only solution that I can think is looping inside the push method but i'm having trouble looping inside it. there is no error to it but it won't display the data.

```
memberLists.push(
    dataProps.map((dts) => {
      dts: freBaseData[frdata][dts]
    })
);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

My current code(Listwrap.js) My Listwrap component:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      attribte: this.props,
      dataShow: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const dataList = firebase.database().ref(this.state.attribte.type);

    dataList.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      let freBaseData = snapshot.val();
      let dataStorage = [];
      let dataProps = this.state.attribte.data; // contains an array ['fname', 'lname', 'mname'] can also contain different array depends on the props of component calling this component

      for(let frdata in freBaseData) {
        dataStorage.push({
          fname: freBaseData[frdata].fname,
          mname: freBaseData[frdata].mname,
          lname: freBaseData[frdata].lname
        }); // should be dynamic
      }

      this.setState({
        dataShow: dataStorage
      });
    });
  }
```

Then I call them on my dashboard Component(Dashboard.js):

```
<div>
   <Listwrap type="Members" data={['fname','mname','lname']}/>
   <Listwrap type="Announcements" data={['title','date']}/> // no content since it just a display of the title
</div>
```

Comment: can you please define "dynamic"

Comment: Hi @Josh Pittman. I mean by dynamic is that when a component(ex. Dashboard component) calls this component I have a problem with, I call this component as `<Listwrap />`. In my dashboard component I call listwrap as `<Listwrap type="Members" data={['fname', 'mname', 'lname']}/>` So the Listwrap component dynamically just call the props from my dashboard. Where I can also call Listwrap again as `<Listwrap type="Announcements" data={['title', 'date']}/>`